# Examples demonstrating that the finitely generated hypothesis in Nakayama's lemma is necessary

Tags: commutative-algebra

Recall that Nakayama's lemma states that

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $J$ be the Jacobson radical of $R$ (the intersection of all the maximal ideals of $R$). For any finitely generated $R$-module $M$, if $IM=M$ for some ideal $I\subseteq J$, then $M=0$.

I was trying to come up with a simple / illustrative example of the above situation where $M$ is non-zero and *not finitely generated*, but $IM=M$ for some $I\subseteq J$.

The only example I managed to come up with was 
$$R=k[[\overline{x}_0,\overline{x}_1,\overline{x}_2,\ldots]]=k[[x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots]]/(x_0^2,x_1^2-x_0,x_2^2-x_1,\ldots)$$
where $k$ is a field, and $I=M=(\overline{x}_0,\overline{x}_1,\overline{x}_2,\ldots)\neq0$. Since $k[[x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots]]$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, we have that $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $I$, so that $I$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$, and $$IM=I^2=(\overline{x}_0^2,\overline{x}_1^2,\overline{x}_2^2,\ldots,\overline{x}_0\overline{x}_1,,\ldots,\overline{x}_1\overline{x}_2,\ldots)=(0,\overline{x}_0,\overline{x}_1,\ldots,\overline{x}_0\overline{x}_1,\ldots,\overline{x}_1\overline{x}_2,\ldots)\supseteq I$$
so that $IM=I^2=I=M$.

Is there an easier example - maybe with $R$ noetherian? Also, what is the geometric picture here? As I understand it, letting $M$ be non-finitely generated corresponds to looking at non-coherent sheaves, which I don't have a whole lot of intuition for - even less than my novice understanding of coherent  sheaves.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My favorite example is $R = \mathbf Z_{(p)}$ [which is very Noetherian] and $M = \mathbf Q$. Of course, you then think of localizing $R = k[x]$.

On that note, there was a thread on MO about understanding the lemma and [Roy Smith's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61446/how-to-memorise-understand-nakayamas-lemma-and-its-corollaries/61448#61448) there is pretty geometric: "It's sort of like the inverse function theorem".

Comment: +1 for the speed with which you gave the best possible example and the link to Roy's answer. You remind me of the gun slingers in the films I loved to watch in my youth :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for your kind words, as usual. And I love the proof that, e.g., $\mathbf Q$ is not finitely generated! On a serious note, the man with no name didn't have to write a thesis, so I should probably start cutting down :-/

Answer (score 18):

If $(R,\mathfrak m)$ is a local domain which is  not a field, then for its fraction field $K$ we have $\mathfrak m K=K$.

Amusingly, this proves that $K$ is not a finitely generated  $R$-module.